# Передать значение input в модал

Tags: javascript, html, django

Допустим есть у меня input, значение которого нужно передать в input, который находится в Modal. Подскажите, как можно реализовать это. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var value = $('#first_input').val();
$('#second_input').val(value);
```

Если делать при вводе в первый инпут, то:

```
$('#fisrt_input').change(function(){
     var value = $('#first_input').val();
     $('#second_input').val(value);
});
```

first_input - инпут, куда вводят текст
second_input - инпут модального окна